# using npm packages in a vanilla html/css/js website with browserify

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to build a plain HTML/CSS website with some npm modules. I have experience in React but I can't get it to work.

What I want to achieve:

A page called index.html with a swiper (https://swiperjs.com/). I don't want to use react or anything.

What I did so far:

1. I created a new npm project/package.json file.
2. I installed browserify and esmify as dependencies
3. I added the following scripts to my package.json:

```
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel start:server start:js start:sass",
    "start:server": "serve",
    "start:js": "browserify ./js/app.js -p esmify > ./js/bundle.js",
    "start:sass": "sass --watch scss/style.scss:css/style.css"
```

4. I created a file called `app.js` (in the folder js/) and added the following content:

```
import Swiper from 'swiper';
import 'swiper/css';

const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
    direction: 'horizontal',
    loop: true
});
```

(I got this content from this page: https://swiperjs.com/get-started)
5) I created an html file with the following content:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="nl">
    <head>
        <title>My website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="swiper">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide">slide 1</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">slide 2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="./js/bundle.js" defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When i run `npm run start`, I get the following error:

> Error: Can't walk dependency graph: Cannot find module 'swiper/css' from 'js/app.js'

When I leave out `import 'swiper/css'`, the page loads but I don't see a swiper. I have added some styling to the slider divs. I see the .slider-div, but I dont see the .slider-slide-divs.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: did you tried adding type="module" to your <Script> tag?

Comment: yes it doesn't work